# Modifying PATH does not work

Tags: bash, eclipse

I want to add `/home/myname/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130219/eclipse` to PATH.

I edited .profile:

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH:/home/myname/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130219/eclipse"
```

but it won't work. Why?

When I instead save `export PATH=/home/myname/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130219/eclipse:$PATH`
in a file in `/etc/profile.d/` and do `chmod a+x` it works.

Both should work. I would like to understand why the first option does not work.

Comment: Have you tried adding `export` to `.profile` as well?

Comment: Yes I tried that but it did not work.

Comment: Actually, some clarification required: what "doesn't work"? Does the new directory fail to appear in `$PATH`?

Answer (score 0):

Is `/home/myname/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130219/eclipse` a directory or actually the program you want to execute? If the latter, your .profile should contain

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH:$HOME/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130219"
```

Comment: No the program I want to run, eclipse, is in the directory home/myname/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130219/eclipse

Comment: After you edited ~/.profile, did you re-source it? `. ~/.profile`

Comment: Also, do you have a `~/.bash_profile` file? If you do, bash won't read `~/.profile` -- http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files

Comment: No I do't have a  `~/.bash_profile`, and yes I did source it after editing.

Comment: Oh I am so embarrassed! Thanks Glenn for you effort!!! I can't even vote you up cos I am new. It works exactly liked you wrote, and I had done it like that, except that I added the new path between `if` and `fe` and since I do not have a `/bin` directory in my home directory I could wait forever that my path will be exported.